# SSL endpoint on a WCF service with only XML configuration file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service with only the xml configuration file and the .exe (so not the complete solution). Can i make existing endpoints secure with https?
If so, how can i do this and how can i connect to it with my client which will be on another pc in the network?

this will be my service xml config:
my binding:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding
      name="HighQuotaWSHttpBinding"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      useDefaultWebProxy="false"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

my endpoint:

```
 <service
    behaviorConfiguration="WebDataServiceBehaviour"
    name="Humiq.Integral.WebDataService.Impl.ServiceLayer.WcfLibrary.WebDataService">
    <endpoint
      address="WebDataService"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HighQuotaWSHttpBinding"
      contract="Humiq.Integral.WebDataService.Intf.ServiceLayer.IWebDataService"
      name="WebDataServiceHttpBinding">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange"
      name="mexManagement" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://mylocalip:9650/" />
        <add baseAddress="https://mylocalip:9651/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

behaviour:

```
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <!-- Behavior for WebserviceData interface -->
    <behavior name="WebDataServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- Set throttling of (concurrent) cals -->
      <serviceThrottling
         maxConcurrentCalls="100"
         maxConcurrentSessions="100"
         maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And this is my client:

```
  <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebDataServiceHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mylocalip:9651/WebDataService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WebDataServiceHttpBinding" contract="wcf1.IWebDataService"
            name="WebDataServiceHttpBinding">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
```

Comment: App.config or Web.Config?  I.o.w how is it hosted?

Comment: sorry it is an XML configuration file. It is hosted on a pc on the same network.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: how are you hosting it? IIS or service?

Comment: Are your services self hosted via the exe?

Comment: so any one got a anwser?

Comment: can you share your end point configuration

Comment: yes of course this is from the service http://pastebin.com/GGe6YaTb

Comment: Don't use pastebin, select the relevant part of the config and post it here. Note that you can _edit_ your question.

Comment: You'll need to do a bit more than editing your configuration file - configuring certificates, for one thing - but this should help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24027/SSL-with-Self-hosted-WCF-Service

Comment: Ian it doesnt fix my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the port to use ssl on windows.

it is done with the netsh command, you can read its help:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8732 certhash=4745537760840034c3dea27f940a269b7d470114 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

Comment: what is the problem now? are you able to start the service?

Comment: yes i can start the service the console says the client certificate is not provided

Comment: check out here how to use th command line to require a client ceritificate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx. then make sure the client really provides one